# In SQL or mySQL, how can I determine the highest sum of a someone with an associated key?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

if I have the table above, waiter 1102 has the most tips, because he makes $70 tips in total. 
But in SQL, how can I write a query that find the waiter who makes the most tips. In this case, I want to find waiter 1102 who makes the most tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve all waiters who have the largest tip amount, including all waiters who are tied, then you may try the following query:

```
SELECT WaiterID, SUM(Tips) AS total_tips
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY WaiterID
HAVING SUM(Tips) = (SELECT MAX(Tips) FROM (SELECT SUM(Tips) AS Tips
                                           FROM yourTable
                                           GROUP BY WaiterID) t);
```

You could also use the `LIMIT` trick here.  But that would not return all ties in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

In **MySQL:**

```
SELECT Waiter, sum(tips)Tips
FROM T
GROUP BY waiter
ORDER BY sum(tips) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In **SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 Waiter, sum(tips)Tips
FROM T
GROUP BY waiter
ORDER BY sum(tips) DESC
```

Comment: The OP didn't tag with SQL Server, but you should mention `TOP 1 WITH TIES` as an option in SQL Server.

Comment: what does "sum(tips)Tips" do?

Comment: It Adds the Tips(20+50) for the waiters.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be  "sum(tips)" instead of " sum(tips)Tips"?

Comment: @RoganFarrira, I just Give [Alias Name](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm) to the Result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `limit`:

```
select waiter, sum(tips)
from t
group by waiter
order by sum(tips) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the results you've asked for

```
1. select sum(tips),waiterid from tablename group by waiterid
```

If you want to sort by highest sum then sort by tips

```
2. select sum(tips),waiterid from tablename group by waiterid sort by tips desc
```